# How can I install the Azerbaijani language?

Tags: magento2, language

Please help me create a new language. There is no Azerbaijani language in the database of Magento.

Comment: Do you want to add translations or new currency/decimal delimeter/etc..?

Comment: Not only on the cover of the site.

Comment: I created categories, there I can choose different languages. But when I turn to other languages, the site does not translate.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/hvhaoq

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I can't find any AZ language pack for Magento. Thus, there is no easy way to add support of AZ locale. If you are a native speaker, you can translate any or all words and phrases in the Magento application using a language package:

- Collect all phrases using collect CLI command `./bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/var/www/html/magento2/az_AZ.csv" -m`
- Translate the second column of csv file
- Pack the dictionary using pack CLI command `./bin/magento i18n:pack /var/www/html/magento2/az_AZ.csv -d az_AZ`
- Create a directory for the language package like `/var/www/html/magento2/app/i18n/YourVendor/az_AZ
- Add composer.json, language.xml and registration.php to this directory

For more detailed steps refer to any guide about language packages in Magento 2. For example - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html